# Creating modules/types visible only to F# projects

Tags: f#, inline

Is it possible to make a module or type visible only to F# projects? Active patterns aren't visible to other languages, but I assume that's due to their not being valid identifiers in those languages. Is there another way of achieving the same effect for modules/types?

Comment: I want C# consumers of the library to use methods and F# users to use the related module. It's not essential, but since there's a lot of overlap between the type and module, it would clean up the interface for users within their respective language.

Comment: It's against interoperability spirit of .NET framework. Don't we all want these languages interoperable?

Comment: Interoperable doesn't have to mean 'the same interface in every language'. If it did, a good bit of F# would not be in this category.

Answer (score 3):

Is this awful?

```
[<AutoOpen>]
module ``(|Hidden|)`` = 
  module MyModule =
    let f() = ()
```

`MyModule` only appears in F#.

Comment: This is a devious solution. I love it.

Answer (score 1):

I think I might just put the F#-specific APIs in an F# module, and put a doc comment on the module that steers C# folks towards the appropriate namespaces/types for them.

Comment: I guess this means there isn't a way to use F# metadata to hide modules/types?

Comment: @Brian: My goal here is to use `let`-bound functions in F#--for better type inference, pipelining, etc--and methods in C#. But I think C# users will wonder why there's `Foo` _and_ `FooModule`, with a lot of overlap.

Comment: The only examples of this in the Core lib are types meant to be used primarily from F# (`FSharpList`, `FSharpMap`, etc). The usage across languages isn't intended to be comparable, as I'm hoping for in my case.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. In my case I implemented some async functionality in F#, and I wanted to have essentially the same API, but returning `Async<T>` for F#, `Task<T>` for C# 5 consumers, and just `T` for people who don't want to deal with async.

What I ended up doing was creating three sub-namespaces (Async, Sync, and FSharp) and defining the same interface in all three namespaces, differing only by return type.

Then on the class containing the actual implementation, I implemented all three interfaces, and made a set of static factory methods that just create an instance of the class and cast it to the appropriate interface.

Consumers can then call `SomeClass.CreateAsync()` or `SomeClass.CreateSync()` or `SomeClass.CreateFSharp()` to get an interface appropriate to their environment. They don't have to explicitly open any of the three sub-namespaces.

I suppose I also could have done it in terms of extension methods, at least if I only wanted two implementations. F# can define both F#-style and C#-style extension methods, but a C# consumer will ignore the F# extensions, and an F# consumer will ignore the C#-style extensions.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would work:

Everywhere you have

```
let ...
```

replace it with

```
let inline ...
```

then the functions can't be called from C# as the C# compiler can't use F# inline functions

Comment: Interesting idea, but possibly with an impact on performance.

Comment: @Daniel - I don't think performance would be too terrible but perhaps more importantly `let rec` can't be hidden